# backbone-forms.js - can i set minlength like in jQuery validate or have i to validate on my own after rendering the backbone form?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-forms

here is my form: can i set validation rules inside this definition or have i
to validate over it by hand with conditional statements or is something like this already build in?

i would like to set for learning purposes the minlength to 20 without conditionals of my own.
or shall i extend the plugin by including them in the plugin file?

```
var form1 = new Backbone.Form({
schema: {
    country: { type: 'Select', options: ['UK', 'USA'] },
    city: { type: 'Select', options: cities.UK },
    message: { validators: ['required', 'message'] }
}
```

}).render();

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Comment: this is the one im trying to use: https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms

Comment: In most cases, you do your validation on the `Model` itself and not the `View` just a future FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a minimum length rule as a regular expression:

```
message: { validators: [ 'required', /.{20,}/ ] }
```

All the validation options are [documented here](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#validation).